# IntelliJ is not saving text with file, while trying , IndexOutOfBoundsException while extracting data from SQL insert statements in Kotlin

Tags: sql, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have 10k line of text(insert for SQL) where dataclass is not as I want, so I have my dataclass and logic to correct and fit to my dataclass but when I use Intellij to save outcome as text. txt file is being saved but empty??

```
data class NamesData(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val gender: String,
val meaning: String,
val origin: String
)
fun main() {
val sqlInsertStatements = """
insert into all_names (Id, Word, Meaning, is_user_added) values (54143, 'Abadjon', '<p style="text-align: end;">\<span style="color: #0000ff;"\>O''g''il bolalar ismi\</span\></p><p>Ism qismi: Jon</p><p>KELIB CHIQISHI:\<br<br</br> Arabcha</p><br><p><strong>MA’NOSI:</strong></p><p>Mangu, cheksiz, abadiy, umri uzoq</p>', null);
insert into all_names (Id, Word, Meaning, is_user_added) values (54144, 'Abay', '<p style="text-align: end;">\<span style="color: #0000ff;"\>O''g''il bolalar ismi\</span\></p><p></p><p>KELIB CHIQISHI:\<br<br</br> O''zbekcha</p><br><p><strong>MA’NOSI:</strong></p>
<p>Hushyor, ehtiyotkor yoki himoya, muhofaza qilingan</p>', null);
""".trimIndent()

    val formattedNamesList = formatNames(sqlInsertStatements)
    val insertStatements = createInsertStatements(formattedNamesList)
    
    val filePath = "${getFilePath()}/formatted_names.txt"
    saveToFile(insertStatements, filePath)
    println("File saved successfully at: $filePath")

}

fun formatNames(sql: String): List\<NamesData\> {
val idRegex = "Id, (\\d+),".toRegex()
val nameRegex = "Word, '(\[^'\]+)',".toRegex()
val meaningRegex = "Meaning, '(\[^'\]+?)'.*?span\[^\>\]+\>(\[^\<\]+)\</span\>.*?KELIB CHIQISHI:\<br<br</br>(\[^\<\]+)</p>".toRegex()

    val idMatches = idRegex.findAll(sql).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }
    val nameMatches = nameRegex.findAll(sql).map { it.groupValues[1] }
    val meaningMatches = meaningRegex.findAll(sql).map {
        val gender = it.groupValues[1]
        val meaning = it.groupValues[2]
        val origin = it.groupValues[3]
        Triple(gender, meaning, origin)
    }
    val formattedNamesList = mutableListOf<NamesData>()
    
    for ((id, name) in idMatches.zip(nameMatches)) {
        val (gender, meaning, origin) = meaningMatches.elementAtOrElse(id - 54143) { Triple("", "", "") }
        formattedNamesList.add(NamesData(id, name, gender, meaning, origin))
    }
    return formattedNamesList

}
fun createInsertStatements(namesList: List\<NamesData\>): String {
val insertStatements = StringBuilder()

    for (namesData in namesList) {
        insertStatements.appendLine("insert into all_names (Id, name, gender, meaning, origin) values (${namesData.id}, \"${namesData.name}\", \"${namesData.gender}\", \"${namesData.meaning}\", \"${namesData.origin}\");")
    }
    return insertStatements.toString()

}
fun saveToFile(text: String, filePath: String) {
val file = File(filePath)
try {
BufferedWriter(FileWriter(file)).use { writer -\>
writer.write(text)
}
} catch (e: IOException) {
println("Error while writing to the file: ${e.message}")
}
}
fun getFilePath(): String {
return System.getProperty("user.dir")
}
```

was expecting to see saved txt result like bolow
insert into all_names (Id, name, gender, meaning, origin) values (54143, "Abadjon", "O'gil bolalar ismi", "Ism qismi: Jon", "Arabcha");
insert into all_names (Id, name, gender, meaning, origin) values (54144, "Abay", "O'gil bolalar ismi", "", "O'zbekcha");
but not no result
pls help?

Comment: In function `saveToFile`, I don't see that you are closing the `BufferedWriter`. Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: tried same issue, result is not being showed in my run as either

File saved successfully at: /Users/apple/IdeaProjects/DataSQL/formatted_names.txt

Process finished with exit code 0

when I open file it is empty

Comment: You need to debug. I suggest adding more `println`s. Is function `saveToFile` being called? If it is, what parameter values are being passed? What is value of parameter `text`? What is the value of parameter `filePath`?

Comment: @Abra `use` handles closing the stream.

Comment: Your regexes look weird. `"Id, (\\d+),"` doesn't match the structure of your SQL statements. Right after "Id," comes "Word,", not an integer.